# ng-if blocking the directive methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive for Opentoke Library but it's not working when I am using the `ng-if`, the reason of using `ng-if` is for IOS devices webrtc is not supported so it's showing alert after DOM load.

```
<div class="opentok" ng-if="!isMobileView">
  <open-tok-archive></open-tok-archive>
</div>

<a href="javascript:void();" ng-click="myMethod()">click me</a>

<div class="opentok" ng-if="!isMobileView">
  <open-toke-screen-share></open-toke-screen-share>
</div>
```

without `ng-if` every thing is working fine.

Direcitve

```
'use strict';
var session, apiKey, publisher, openTokToken, archiveID;

angular.module('app')
  .directive('openTokArchiv', [function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      templateUrl: 'views/pages/openTokArchive.html',
      controller: function (OpenTokService, OTSession, $window, $rootScope, $scope, $routeParams, $cookieStore) {


      $scope.myMethod = function (){
               console.log("---------not-- working ---------")
           }
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Please paste your directive

Comment: there is a link outside of directive which call the method of directive which is not working after ng-if

Comment: I added the directive sample

Comment: You are showing HTML directive of <open-toke-screen-share>  and giving sample of directive 'openTokArchive'. So it is difficult to under stand your problem. Please correct it.

Comment: I did it and also added the link please let me know what is the wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-show/ng-hide instead of ng-if.

**EDITS**

```
  <div class="opentok" ng-if="!isMobileView">
    <open-tok-archive></open-tok-archive>
  </div>
```

Have a look at this plunker [Demo link](https://plnkr.co/edit/ji98Pl1CDe6PR4JBjZtM?p=preview)

> Try this without ng-if #working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="variables">
      <div class="opentok">
        <open-tok-archive></open-tok-archive>
      </div>

      <button type="button" ng-click="myMethod()">Toggle</button>

    </body>

</html>
```

> With ng-if it is not working

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="variables">
  <div class="opentok" ng-if="!isMobileView">
    <open-tok-archive></open-tok-archive>
  </div>

  <button type="button" ng-click="myMethod()">Toggle</button>

</body>
```

Comment: I don't want to append element on HTML DOM

Comment: Can you post the JS code where you are loading URL?

Comment: I am not using any loading the url < this is a simple directive with some $scope methods but after using ng-if it is not working else it is working

Comment: It is very difficult to solve the issue without sufficient info.

Comment: I already added the sample of directive the method is not invoke after using ng-if

Comment: <button type="button" ng-click="myMethod()">Toggle</button> try this not working

Comment: I think this is scope related issue which is not wokring after ng-if

Comment: #Nagaveer you understand my issue ?